# settings.DEBUG is still false regardless if set to True

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-1.7

I am using Django==1.7.11, mysql, python 2.7.

In my settings file I have debug set to True, I've confirmed this by entering the django shell and consistently I get `True`.

```
>>> from django.conf import settings
>>> settings.DEBUG
True
```

But in my `tests.py` file:

```
import unittest

from django.conf import settings
import settings as settingsfile
from django.test import LiveServerTestCase

class SeleniumTest(LiveServerTestCase):

    def test_nothing(self):
        print 'File DEBUG is: %s' % (settingsfile.DEBUG, )
        print 'Django DEBUG is: %s' % (settings.DEBUG, )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()

>>>> File DEBUG is: True
>>>> Django DEBUG is: False
```

Is there anywhere else that the value of DEBUG could have changed or some misuse of importing settings in test files that I'm not aware of??

**== UPDATE ==**

This [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/django-developers/J6toltyOI1Q/O_h1zwYOdTIJ) mentions that `LiveServerTestCase` forces `DEBUG=False` so that it mimics a production server but I changed my file to use Django's normal `TestCase` and end up with the same results.

import unittest

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.test import TestCase
import settings as settingsfile

class SeleniumTest(TestCase):

    def test_nothing(self):
        print 'File DEBUG is: %s' % (settingsfile.DEBUG, )
        print 'Django DEBUG is: %s' % (settings.DEBUG, )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()

>>>> File DEBUG is: True
>>>> Django DEBUG is: False
```

Comment: @DRC Yeah I think you're right

Answer (score 3):

Django's tests run with DEBUG=False.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/overview/#other-test-conditions